# Using a manifest causes window to remain partially blank

Tags: c++, mfc, manifest, visual-styles

I am in the process of trying to make an app that has most of its development done in Visual C++ 6.0 adhere to Windows theming, or to be precise the visual styles aspect of it. The application in question is a MFC application with the MBCS characterset. Getting theming to kick in in the first place required the `InitCommonControlsEx(...);` trick combined with the proper manifests for the Common Controls 6.0. Nothing special thus far.

With all that done, I have tons of windows which have some semblance of drawing glitches showing - white rectangles on the background where there used to be gray like there is in the rest of the window, but they do not hinder.

The biggest troublemaker is in a `CDialog` descendant that implements an (archaic) 'did you know...' tip dialog. It refuses to draw anything other than the  buttons, checkbox and decorative frame the moment the manifest is in place. However, if I take the manifest OUT, everything works fine.

[Comparison images right after invoking the dialog](http://img825.imageshack.us/img825/2969/tipoftheday.png)

I have already stepped through the `OnPaint` code (which draws the icon and the 'did you know' text, and all functions return sensible and successful values. I also tried removing the entire customdrawn bits (commented out the mappings for the `WM_PAINT` and `WM_CTLCOLOR` messages), but even that caused nothing to show or act different for that matter.

Once I click the 'Next Tip' button, it *will* properly paint the next tip in the list. However, the customdrawn header with the bulb icon remains missing.

The code really does nothing special that I can spot, and I'm at a loss. Since I suspect the dialog definition is of most help, I'll include that, although I can post other things if people have ideas on where the problems are hiding.

```
IDD_TIP DIALOG DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 231, 164
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Tip of the Day"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    CONTROL         "",IDC_STATIC,"Static",SS_BLACKFRAME,12,11,207,123
    LTEXT           "Some String",IDC_TIPSTRING,28,63,177,60
    CONTROL         "&Show Tips on StartUp",IDC_STARTUP,"Button",
                    BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP,13,146,85,10
    PUSHBUTTON      "&Next Tip",IDC_NEXTTIP,109,143,50,14,WS_GROUP
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "&Close",IDOK,168,143,50,14,WS_GROUP
    CONTROL         "",IDC_BULB,"Static",SS_BITMAP,20,17,190,111
END
```

The machine I am testing this on is a W7 64-bit machine running VS2010. The application in question itself is 32-bit.

Edit:

A new day provides new insights. Somehow, the issue is with the handling of the `WM_CTLCOLOR` message. When I set it to return a `NULL_BRUSH`, I finally saw things being drawn (that of course blurred on top of another after initial drawing). Nailing it down even further, it seems that when `nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_STATIC`, if I return a `NULL_BRUSH`, stuff will display. The moment I make it a `WHITE_BRUSH` nothing gets drawn again, however.

Original code:

```
HBRUSH CTipDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    if (pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_TIPSTRING)
        return (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    else if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_STATIC)
        /* Visual styles enabled causes the things we draw in our WM_PAINT
         * to get cleared (and not redrawn) if we do not use a hollow brush here.
         * Likely the default behaviour differs when using theming. */
        return (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH);
        
    return CDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
}
```

Problem solved! The lines that are in bold are what I changed to fix my problem, including the obligatory comments. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, version 6 of the Common Controls only officially supports Unicode.

According to [a blog entry by Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/11/06/9045610.aspx), those controls work with the ANSI character set to a degree, but only for backwards compatibility reasons. No one should be using that intentionally.

> If you're an ANSI application and you create controls from the common controls library, you may encounter strange behavior. It'll mostly work, but things may be weird at the fringe.
>
> ...
>
> And it means that all you folks who are using version 6 of the common controls but haven't converted to Unicode are relying on a compatibility loophole. The ANSI support is there for the old programs that thought they were talking to a version 5 common control; it isn't there for you.

I've never tried doing such a thing so I cannot say for sure, but you may be encountering some of this "strange behavior". If that is the case, then the only officially supported options would be to either convert to Unicode or go back to using version 5 of the controls. Otherwise you would be left trying to find workarounds to any odd behavior you might find, and that doesn't sound like a good situation to be in.

Comment: I was aware of the Unicode <-> MBCS issue before I started. The way I understood it however was that there would be quirkiness regarding character sets; especially the edit control as Raymond pointed out in his blog post. Converting to Unicode might be something for away at the horizon, but right now I kinda refuse to believe that there is quirkiness with this trivial dialog, as all input/output remains in the ASCII range at this time. I've got _far_ more complicated windows with funky drawing stuff that work just fine.

Comment: Since you are the only answer, and it is a helpful one (despite not answering or addressing the root of my problem), I'll accept your answer. Thanks for taking the time on an indepth reply. :)